# String variable in a regular expression in bash?

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I have to write a regular expression in shell script to get a string inside another string, so that my variable string `myString` occurs in the regular expression string. How can I do this?

Comment: it would help if you tell more on what you want to do. what do you mean  by "take myString"? do myString change, and what is constant in the context of the expression you want to match?

Comment: Out of which String? [Possibly this helps](http://bashshell.net/regular-expressions/features-of-regular-expressions/)

Comment: @CharlesB I edited my question. Could you please take a look ?

Comment: *"myString is a constant string"* ... unless I'm missing something here, you don't need regular expression if you're matching a constant string. Are you trying to extract everything inside the double quotes? Is the text outside the double quotes constant?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract text within the double quotes, and assuming there's only one set of double quotes, one way to do that is:

```
[me@home]$ echo $A
to get "myString" in regular expression
[me@home]$ echo $A | sed -n 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p'
myString
```

Of course, if there's only one set of quotes you can also do without sed/regex:

```
[me@home]$ echo $A | cut -d'"' -f2
myString
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know there will only be one set of double quotes, you could use [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) like this:

```
zsh> s='to get "myString" in regular expression'
zsh> echo ${${s#*\"}%\"*}
mystring
```

bash doesn't support multilevel expansion, so the expansion needs to be applied sequentially:

```
bash> s='to get "myString" in regular expression'
bash> s=${s#*\"}
bash> s=${s%\"*}
bash> echo $s
mystring
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>echo 'hi "there" ' | perl -pe 's/.*(["].*["])/\1/g'
"there"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'awk':

```
echo 'this is string with "substring" here' | awk '/"substring"/ {print}'

# awk '/"substring"/ {print}' means to print string, which contains regexp "this"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you can use the **=~** operator in a [**[[ ... ]]** conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b), together with the [**BASH_REMATCH** variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fREMATCH).

Example of use:

```
TEXT='hello "world", how are you?'
if [[ $TEXT =~ \"(.*)\" ]]; then
    echo "found ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} between double quotes."
else
    echo "nothing found between double quotes."
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

[grep](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html) is the most common tool for finding regular expressions in the shell.

Comment: yeap, I know I can use grep like this : grep -P '.*".*".*' -o [FILE] however, I wanna to get string inside double quotes. @Bitwise